# Разница между addressof и &

Tags: c++

В чём разница между `std::addressof<>(var)` и `&var`?

```
int var = 42;

std::cout << std::addressof(var);
std::cout << '\n';
std::cout << &var;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница в том, что унарный оператор `&` может быть перегружен для класс- или enum-типов, делать что-то постороннее и возвращать что-то, не имеющее никакого отношения к адресу объекта. А `std::addressof` всегда возвращает именно адрес объекта. Например, при написании шаблонного кода для получения адреса объекта некоего обобщенного типа `T` следует использовать именно `std::addressof`, а не унарный `&` - тем самым вы защитите свой шаблонный код от "неожиданностей".

Для `int var` разницы никакой нет.

Answer (score 3):

`std::addressof` нельзя использовать для получения адреса нестатического метода или поля класса.

Comment: Можете привести пример, как это сделать для `&`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `struct foo{void bar1(void) {}}; auto p = ::std::addressof(foo::bar1); // ошибка`

Comment: @titan `struct foo{void bar1(void) {}}; auto p = &foo::bar1; // ок`

Comment: @VTT: Ошибка в варианте `std::addressof(foo::bar1)` не имеет никакого отношения к `std::addressof`. В языке С++ `foo::bar1` уже само по себе не является корректным выражением, еще на уровне синтаксиса. В выражении синтаксис `foo::bar1` может быть применен только после `&` или перед `()`.

Comment: @AnT `struct foo{static void bar1(void) {}}; auto p = ::std::addressof(foo::bar1); // OK`

Comment: @VTT: В моем комментарии речь идет именно о нестатическом члене `bar1`. Qualified-id *нестатического* члена класса не может использоваться в качестве самостоятельного [под]выражения. В С++ просто нет такого синтаксиса выражения. В выражении qualified-id *нестатического* члена класса может встречаться только в компании с `&` или `()`. Так что к `std::addressof`, еще раз, эта ошибка не имеет никакого отношения.